# Transform data type in Azure Data Factory between tables

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to copy the contents of a certain table to another, both stored in the Azure database, but I'm wondering whether I can change the data type of a certain field, i.e: if there's a field in table 1 whose type is a char, and I want to copy it to table 2, but change its type to byte, is it possible?

Comment: Do this using SQL in the database, eg `CAST`.  If you do want to use ADF  as some kind of orchestration, use a Stored Proc task.

Comment: If you want to do it in ADF, use data flows. There are casting functions that you use in a Derived Column: toString(), toDouble(), toBoolean(), etc ...

Comment: what's your sink table schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these two tables are in the same database then the easiest way to do this would be to use T-SQL, eg

```
INSERT INTO yourTargetTable ( col1, col2 ...
SELECT
    CAST( col1 AS INT ),
    CAST( col2 AS CHAR(1) ),
    ...
FROM yourTable
```

Byte is not a SQL Server data type, so please post some sample data and expected results.

If the tables are in different databases then you may have a case for using Data Factory - please post back with further information.